# React state as compute state depend on other state property

Tags: reactjs, react-state

```
state = {
   tips [{active: false, amount: 10}, {active: true, amount: 50}, {active: false, amount: 10}]
   active_tip_amount: // compute logic //
}
```

is there any way to get `active_tip_amout` computed from active tips?

this.state.active_tip_amout should be 50 for the above case it computes base on this.state

Comment: Are those values hardcoded? Or are they populated from a different location? Additionally, would you be able to set the tips value initially, and then do a setState for active_tip_amount after the fact?

Comment: yes tips are hardcoded,  initially, active_tip_amout value is 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest that `active_tip_amount` probably doesn't need to be stored in state.

If you are working with derived values, it's often simpler to compute them when they're needed, rather than trying to keep them in sync with the other state whenever it changes.

In this case, you can write a getter (or a method) to compute the active tip amount from the current state, then call it whenever you need to access the computed value.

```
class TipsView extends Component {
  state = {
    tips [{active: false, amount: 10}, {active: true, amount: 50}, {active: false, amount: 10}]
  }

  get active_tip_amount() {
    let activeTip = this.state.tips.find(tip => tip.active);
    if (activeTip) {
      return activeTip.amount;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }

  render() {
    // use the active amount here
    this.active_tip_amount
  }
}
```

This gives you more flexibility to compute that value, including deriving it from props (or even using a function rather than a getter and parameterizing it).

If you have reason to believe that computing the value on-demand is slowing your app down (very unlikely in this case) then you can always memoize the function that's computing it.

You might find it interesting to read about how Redux encourages people to solve this kind of problem with [memoized selectors](https://redux.js.org/recipes/computing-derived-data). The same principles also apply to React component state.

Comment: thanks, it's not related to slowing app because there are only three tips hardcoded.

Comment: Even though `Array#find` is an O(n) operation, it's still very fast. This benchmark https://jsperf.com/array-find-vs-some shows it doing over 1000 ops/second in modern browsers with a list of 100000 items. That's < 1ms per run.

Comment: My guess is that you'd need millions of tips before it started to slow the UI down to the point where it was noticeable.